# interact between two different graphs in two different browser windows in dc.js crossfilter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have created dc.js visualization have four different bar graphs. Also each graph have a button to open that particular graph in new browser window. For that purpose I have created separate HTML file for each graph. I want to interact between the graphs opened in two different windows. Is it possible? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`window.opener` will return a reference to the window object of the window that opened it.

In the first window, you can leave a global reference (let's say `var graphThing` or `window.graphThing`) to whatever object you need to manipulate. Then, the window that's launched from the original window can call `window.opener.graphThing` to access the first window's `graphThing`.

To access a property of the child window (let's say global `var childGraphThing` or `window.childGraphThing`) from the parent that opened it, you can keep a reference to the child window by opening it like this:

```
var childWindow = window.open('childGraph.html', 'blank_');
```

Then, you can access it's properties like this:

```
var childWindowGraphThing = childWindow.childGraphThing;
```

Comment: Further, the particular properties that you need from the first window are the dc instance (in order to join the same chart group and receive events) and the crossfiliter instance (in order to share data).  You may need to explicitly write the crossfilter instance to a window property in order to fetch it from the second window.  It will probably just confuse things to load dc.js in the second window; instead you should just do `window.dc = window.opener.dc;`